# Почему не активизируются скрипты после загрузки файлов вебстраницы на сайт?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сверстал вебстраницу, но загрузкой на сайт занимаюсь не я.

На сколько мне известно, вебстраница в итоге попадает в `iframe`, с чем и связана проблема активизации скрипта: он у меня завязан на взаимодействие с `document`, `window` (эффекты запускаются при достижении определённого места на странице).

Хотелось бы узнать, что это за специфика такая по работе с `iframe`?

---

Фрагмент кода:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10950) {
       $('.anim-31').addClass('anim-3-action anim-31-ef');
       $('.anim-32').addClass('anim-3-action anim-32-ef');
       $('.anim-33').addClass('anim-3-action anim-33-ef');
       $('.anim-34').addClass('anim-3-action anim-34-ef');
       $('.anim-35').addClass('anim-3-action anim-35-ef');
   };
```

Comment: Использовал JQuery

Comment: Какой браузер использовали?

Comment: Я проверил в хроме и фф - одно и то же. Думаю, что дело не в нём. Вот уже вычитал, что возможно мне нужно было обращаться к айдишнику айфрейма в JQ-обёртке. Что скажете?

Comment: всё что вы щас говорите Виртуальность ... что бы как то сказать верно нужно видеть предмет разговора ..т.е код